# Example of a morphism that is not a function

Tags: category-theory, morphism

Can someone please give me a simple example(I'm not a math professional) of a categorical morphism that is not a function?

Comment: HInt: Some think of categories as partially ordered sets.

Comment: @Derek Thanks, didn't find it myself.

Comment: @John Thanks John.